# How Can I get text from piechart

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I have use MP Android pie chart lib, here I am showing text into piechart , I also want to get this text out side the chart.

I want to get the text (xvals) when clicked on pie chart. Let say when I click on a part of pie chart then it should get text value of it(eg, uber,paytm)

Code

```js
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PieChart pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.piechart);
        pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);

        datatext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.datatext);

        datatitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.datatitle);

        // IMPORTANT: In a PieChart, no values (Entry) should have the same
    // xIndex (even if from different DataSets), since no values can be
    // drawn above each other.
    ArrayList<Entry> yvalues = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        yvalues.add(new Entry(24f, 0));
        yvalues.add(new Entry(15f, 1));
        yvalues.add(new Entry(19f, 2));
        yvalues.add(new Entry(22f, 3));
        yvalues.add(new Entry(20f, 4));
        //yvalues.add(new Entry(17f, 5));

    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yvalues, "Balances");

    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

        xVals.add("Monthly Expenses");
        xVals.add("Phonepe");
        xVals.add("Uber");
        xVals.add("Paytm");
        xVals.add("Savings");
       // xVals.add("Ola");
        dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
    // In Percentage term
        data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    // Default value
    //data.setValueFormatter(new DefaultValueFormatter(0));
        pieChart.setData(data);
        pieChart.setDescription("Savings");

        pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
        pieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(25f);
        pieChart.setHoleRadius(25f);

        dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);

        data.setValueTextSize(13f);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        pieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

        pieChart.animateXY(1400, 1400);


}

    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {

        
        if (e == null)
            return;
        Log.i("VAL SELECTED",
                "Value: " + e.getVal() + ", xIndex: " + e.getXIndex()
                        + ", DataSet index: " + dataSetIndex);

        float datatt = e.getVal();
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+datatt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        datatext.setText(""+datatt);
        //datatitle.setText(""+title);
    }
```

How can I get the text value of chart and show it on different textviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatext.setText(pieChart.getXAxis().getValues().get(e.getXIndex()));
```

or

```
Sting data = ArrayList.get((int) e.getX());
```